# Generic Extension method

Tags: c#

Мне нужно написать extension method ThisDoesntMakeAnySense, метод должен быть generic IEnumerable,который принимает два параметра

1. Предикат для фильтра(которому передается элемент для тестирования и возврашает
   true/false)
2. Делегат с помощью которого метод создает новую запись

Принцип работы метода: если метод не найдет элемент то он возвращает новую запись, а если найдет то он возвращает default значение.

Exention Method

```
    public static class ExetionMethodForList
    {
        public static IEnumerable<T> ThisDoesntMakeAnySense<T>(this List<T> list, Predicate<T> check)
        {
            return list;
        }
    }
```

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int> arr = new List<int>() { 2, 3, 4 };

            var result = arr.ThisDoesntMakeAnySense<int>();
        }
```

Comment: А в чем проблема то?

Comment: не могу написать это метод , если можете помочь

Comment: Так в чем именно то затруднение? Написать за вас я конечно могу, но смысл?

Comment: 1)Предикат для фильтра(которому передается елемент для тестирования и возврошает true/false) 
где должен быть написан метод которые прверяет элемент

Comment: @TeonaNadiradze Вам нужно просто написать фукцию, которая принимает `int` и возвращает `bool`, например, она может проверять, что переданное ей число больше нуля. И вот имя этой функции вы передаёте потом в ваш метод расширения.

Comment: да она может проверять, что переданное ей число больше нуля, но я хочу чтоб он это число проверил в List который был создан в Main

Comment: @TeonaNadiradze Ну вам привели в ответе ниже пример с `lambda`, хотя там можно и обычную функцию передать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю, верно ли я понял вас, но у меня что-то типа такого вышло:

```
public static class ExetionMethodForList
{
     public static IEnumerable<T> ThisDoesntMakeAnySense<T>(this List<T> list, Func<T, bool> check, Func<T> generator)
    {
        if(!list.Any(check))
        {
            list.Add(generator.Invoke());
        }
    
        return list;
    }
}
```

Применяется так

```
var result = arr.ThisDoesntMakeAnySense<int>(x=> x == 5, () => 5);
```